# MySQL: Return SUBSTR between specific delimiter and next non-unique delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, delimiter, substr

I'm trying to return a SUBSTR between two delimiters. The Problem is, that the second delimiter is non-unique in the whole string.

Example:

testurl.de/some:text/&[uniquedelimiter]=texttoextract:sometext:someothertext

So I want to extract the string between "&[uniquedelimiter]=" and the **next** ":" after the unique delimiter.
The occurrence of ":" in the string is variable.

Right now I'm using a double SUBSTRING_INDEX function, but I get errors if the string contains more than one ":".

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(list_of_urls, '&[uniquedelimiter]=',-1),':')
FROM url_table;
```

I couldn't find a comparable solution on any Community.

Thank you so much for your help,
Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working, maybe you can sort it, not sure:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(
    url,
    (POSITION('&[uniquedelimiter]=' IN url) + LENGTH('&[uniquedelimiter]=')),
    LOCATE(':', url, (POSITION('&[uniquedelimiter]=' IN url) + LENGTH('&[uniquedelimiter]='))) -
    (POSITION('&[uniquedelimiter]=' IN url) + LENGTH('&[uniquedelimiter]='))
)
from bla
```

My strategy was like this:

```
SET @url                   = (SELECT url from bla limit 1);
SET @pos_uniq_deli_start   = POSITION('&[uniquedelimiter]=' IN @url);
SET @uniq_deli_length      = LENGTH('&[uniquedelimiter]=');
SET @pos_uniq_deli_end     = @pos_uniq_deli_start + @uniq_deli_length;
--                           LOCATE(char, field, offset)
SET @pos_colon_after_deli  = LOCATE(':', @url, @pos_uniq_deli_end);
SET @delta_unqi_del_colon  = @pos_colon_after_deli - @pos_uniq_deli_end;

--            SUBSTRING(field, start_pos, length)
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@url,@pos_uniq_deli_end, @delta_unqi_del_colon);
SELECT @result;
```

Comment: Hi Philipp, thanks for your immediate answer. I just tried the code, but it seems that in most cases not the first ":" after the unique delimiter is detected. I will try to tweak your code and let you know about news.

Comment: can you provide a string where it is not working, then i maybe can adjust the query

Comment: i tried all this ones:
`testurl.de/some:te:xt/&[uniquedelimiter]=e:x:t:r:a:c:t:sometext:someothertext
testurl.de/some:te:xt/&[uniquedelimiter]=e:xtract:sometext:someothertext
testurl.de/some:te:xt/&[uniquedelimiter]=extract:sometext:someothertext
testurl.de/some:te:xt/::::::&[uniquedelimiter]=extract:a:a:a:a:a:aa:sometext:someothertext
testurl.de/some:text/&[uniquedelimiter]=text:toextract:sometext:someothertext
testurl.de/some:text/&[uniquedelimiter]=texttoextract:sometext:someothertext`

Comment: Hi Philipp, I reentered the code and I noticed that i had a typo in one of the unique delimiter clauses. Next time I will double check, before I'll give feedback. Sorry, for your extra work - it wouldn't have been necessary! Thank you very very much for your help!!